# How ASP.NET CommandName and CommandArgument values are stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

Does anyone know where CommandName and CommandArgument properties of controls are stored? I am not interested in retrieving them, just to know more about ASP.NET internals and for future page size considerations. :)

I created a simple page containing 3 buttons having their commandArg and CommandName set as follows:

```
<asp:Button Text="Click1" runat="server" CommandArgument="1" CommandName="Delete" OnCommand="CommandExec" />
<asp:Button Text="Click2" runat="server" CommandArgument="2" CommandName="Save" OnCommand="CommandExec" />
<asp:Button Text="Click3" runat="server" CommandArgument="3" CommandName="Copy" OnCommand="CommandExec" />
```

changing CommandArgument or CommandName to a considerably large values do not affect ViewState content and size, so where these values are stored?

thanx

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Feb/20/ViewState-and-OnItemCommand-on-an-ASPNET-Repeater although in comments someone says that _"CommandName/CommandArgument shouldn't have anything to do with ViewState"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand ASP.NET internals, I still think the best book is [Developing ASP.NET Server Controls and Components by Nikhil Kothari and Vandana Datye](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=5728&locale=en-us).  It's written for .NET 1.x, so a bit dated, but still covers the basic architecture really well.

In your example, the reason ViewState size is not affected is that ViewState is not being tracked during the Init phase when the markup is processed.  Property values set to fixed values in the markup will be hardwired in the code generated when the ASP.NET page is compiled.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) gives a good overview of ViewState.

You will see ViewState growing if you put the buttons in a data-bound control such as a repeater or GridView, and use data-binding syntax to have different values for the CommandArgument for each row.

Comment: thanks Joe, I checked the ViewState size in the output markup. Thanks for the book recommendation, but I still emphasize that arguments must be saved somewhere other than ViewState.

Comment: The reason I emphasis that is, if I submit the button and save the argument in a label on the page, the view state (which now contains the argument) will grow! which shows that the view state, if contained the argument, must be relatively large.

Comment: @Bakhshi, In your sample, they are saved in the code that is generated when the page is compiled, because they are fixed values defined in the markup.  If they were dynamic values, e.g. generated during data binding, they would be stored in ViewState.

Comment: AHA! you are right! The markup was the source :D thank you for the point. I changed the commandARgument assignment from markup to code, and the result was as all you guys were saying.

Comment: You also might want to look at this article which explains viewstate deeply: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx Note that ViewState is not used for controls where [`IsItemDirty==false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.isitemdirty.aspx) (unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

it is saved in a viewstate,
please see this post: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Feb/20/ViewState-and-OnItemCommand-on-an-ASPNET-Repeater

Answer (score 2):

These values are indeed stored in the `ViewState`

If you were to test with a simple `GridView` with a button with and without CommandArguments/Names, etc... Then you can see that the ViewState is larger.

However, these values are never going to be really large objects or anything, so I personally wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: thank you Tim, but comparing these two (my sample and grid sample you mentioned) does not support the ViewState storage model. gridview is much complex and terribly depends viewstate for its internal state. But here you can paste a large text in to the CommandArguemnt will not change ViewState size even a bit!

Comment: I would say that if you are concerned about the size of the ViewState with something like this, then you should maybe consider moving to `asp.net-MVC`. Only because you do not work with a ViewState and have greated control over everything.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I recently learned about MVC and I was very handy :)